# Get Saxon XsltTransformer.Run() Result as String

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, saxon

My issue about Saxon XsltTransformer Class is;

I'm testing Saxon .NET samples and according to output of last WriteLine() method, example code below should print validation/transform result to file (outfile), but always redirect result to stdout and file is always empty.

My problem so question is how can i get Xslt validation/transformation result as **string, MemoryStream etc**... My main purpose, make these transactions (XsltTransformer.Run() and other requirements of this transaction and get result) in memory (without creating any file on disk).

I would try make same transactions with memorystream to get result as string (without file on disk) but i didn't get result as file. And i am here...

.NET Version: 4.5

Saxon API Version: SaxonHE9.5N

*Thanks for answers and sorry for my English.*

```
    Uri schemaUri = new Uri(@"file:\\C:\path\to\my.xml");
    Uri xslUri    = new Uri(@"file:\\C:\path\to\my.xsl");
    // Create a Processor instance.
    Processor processor = new Processor();

    // Load the source document
    XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(schemaUri);

    // Create a transformer for the stylesheet.
    XsltTransformer transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(xslUri).Load();

    // Set the root node of the source document to be the initial context node
    transformer.InitialContextNode = input;

    // Create a serializer
    String outfile = "OutputFromXsltSimple2.xml";
    Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(outfile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    serializer.SetOutputStream(fs);

    // Transform the source XML to System.out.
    transformer.Run(serializer);
    //fs.Flush();
    //fs.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("\nOutput written to " + outfile + "\n");
```

**UPDATE:**
In Java side, i am doing this with this code block;

```
TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("/path/to/my.xsl"));


StreamResult sr = new StreamResult();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
sr.setSystemId("DENEMME");

transformer.transform(new StreamSource("/path/to/my.xml"), sr);

System.out.println("----------------");
System.out.println(sw.getBuffer().toString());
```

In XSL,  there is data validation for XML Node values or attribute values. If there is any invalid value according to XSL, all error messages collecting in StreamResult.

I am using Saxon XSLT API for Java and for .NET too. But when i execute working Java example in .NET side, sample App throw exception;

> Provider
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
>   not found.

So i am trying first sample code piece for C#.

**UPDATE 2 (required XML Files for schematron validation):**

Rule XML

Pattern for storing abstract rules

```
<!-- Rule to validate StandardBusinessDocument -->
<sch:rule abstract="true" id="DocumentCheck">
    <sch:assert test="sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader">sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader zorunlu bir elemandır.</sch:assert>
    <sch:assert test="ef:Package">ef:Package zorunlu bir elemandır.</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>

<!-- Rules to validate StandardBusinessDocumentHeader -->
<sch:rule abstract="true" id="HeaderCheck">
    <sch:assert test="sh:HeaderVersion = '1.0'">Geçersiz sh:HeaderVersion elemanı değeri. sh:HeaderVersion elemanı '1.0' değerine eşit olmalıdır.</sch:assert>
    <sch:assert test="count(sh:Sender) = 1">sh:Sender zorunlu bir elemandır.</sch:assert> 
    <sch:assert test="count(sh:Receiver) = 1">sh:Receiver zorunlu bir elemandır.</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>

<!-- Rule to validate given value empty or not -->
<sch:rule abstract="true" id="EmptyCheck">
    <sch:assert test="string-length(normalize-space(string(.))) != 0">Geçersiz <sch:name/> elemanı değeri. Boş olmayan bir değer içermelidir.</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>

<!-- Rule to validate ContactInformation -->
<sch:rule abstract="true" id="ContactInformationCheck">
    <sch:assert test="count(sh:ContactInformation) &gt; 0">En az bir sh:ContactInformation elemanı bulunmalıdır.</sch:assert>
    <sch:assert test="count(sh:ContactInformation[sh:ContactTypeIdentifier = 'VKN_TCKN']) = 1 ">sh:ContactTypeIdentifier elemanı değeri 'VKN_TCKN' ye eşit olan bir tane sh:ContactInformation elemanı bulunmalıdır.</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>

<!-- Rule to validate Contact -->
<sch:rule abstract="true" id="ContactCheck">
    <sch:assert test="sh:ContactTypeIdentifier">sh:ContactTypeIdentifier zorunlu bir elemandır.</sch:assert>
    <sch:assert test="not(sh:ContactTypeIdentifier) or contains($ContactTypeIdentifierType, concat(',',sh:ContactTypeIdentifier,','))">Geçersiz sh:ContactTypeIdentifier değeri : '<sch:value-of select="sh:ContactTypeIdentifier"/>'. Geçerli değerler için kod listesine bakınız.</sch:assert>
    <sch:assert test="not(sh:ContactTypeIdentifier) or not(sh:ContactTypeIdentifier = 'VKN_TCKN') or string-length(sh:Contact) = 11 or string-length(sh:Contact) = 10">sh:ContactTypeIdentifier elemanın değeri 'VKN_TCKN' olması durumunda sh:Contact elemanına 10 haneli vergi kimlik numarası ve ya 11 haneli TC kimlik numarası yazılmalıdır.</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>

<!-- Rule to validate DocumentIdentification.TypeVersion -->
<sch:rule abstract="true" id="TypeVersionCheck">
    <sch:assert test="sh:TypeVersion = '1.0'">Geçersiz sh:TypeVersion elemanı değeri. sh:TypeVersion '1.0' değerine eşit olmalıdır.</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>

<!-- Rule to validate DocumentIdentification.Type -->
<sch:rule abstract="true" id="EnvelopeTypeCheck">
    <sch:assert test="contains($EnvelopeType, concat(',',sh:Type,','))">Geçersiz zarf türü : '<sch:value-of select="sh:Type"/>'. Geçerli değerler için kod listesine bakınız.</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>

<!-- Rule to validate EnvelopeType with given ElementType-->
<sch:rule abstract="true" id="EnvelopeTypeElementTypeCheck">
    <sch:assert test="not(sh:Type = 'SENDERENVELOPE') or not(//ElementType != 'INVOICE')">SENDERENVELOPE türündeki zarf Invoice şemasında göre oluşturulmuş belge taşımalıdır.</sch:assert>
    <sch:assert test="not(sh:Type = 'POSTBOXENVELOPE') or not(//ElementType != 'APPLICATIONRESPONSE')">POSTBOXENVELOPE türündeki zarf ApplicationResponse şemasında göre oluşturulmuş belge taşımalıdır.</sch:assert>
    <sch:assert test="not(sh:Type = 'SYSTEMENVELOPE') or not(//ElementType != 'APPLICATIONRESPONSE')">SYSTEMENVELOPE türündeki zarf ApplicationResponse şemasına göre oluşturulmuş belge taşımalıdır.</sch:assert>
    <sch:assert test="not(sh:Type = 'USERENVELOPE') or (//ElementType = 'PROCESSUSERACCOUNT' or //ElementType = 'CANCELUSERACCOUNT')">USERENVELOPE türündeki zarf ProcessUserAccount ve ya CancelUserAccount şemasına göre oluşturulmuş belge taşımalıdır.</sch:assert>
    <sch:assert test="not(sh:Type = 'USERENVELOPE') or ($receiverId = '3900383669' and $receiverAlias = 'GIB')">USERENVELOPE türündeki zarfı yalnızca 3900383669 vergi kimlik numaralı ve GIB etiketli kullanıcıya gönderebilirsiniz.</sch:assert>
    <sch:assert test="not(sh:Type = 'USERENVELOPE') or ($senderAlias = 'usergb')">USERENVELOPE türündeki zarfı yalnızca 'usergb' etiketine sahip kullanıcı gönderebilir.</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>     

<!-- Rules to validate Package -->
<sch:rule abstract="true" id="ElementsGroupCountCheck">
    <sch:assert test="count(Elements) &lt; 11">ef:Package elemanı içerisinde en fazla 10 tane Elements elemanı olabilir.</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>

<sch:rule abstract="true" id="ElementTypeCheck">
    <sch:assert test="contains($ElementType, concat(',',ElementType,','))">Geçersiz  ElementType değeri : '<sch:value-of select="ElementType"/>'. Geçerli ElementType değerleri için kod listesine bakınız.</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>     

<sch:rule abstract="true" id="ElementCountCheck">
    <sch:assert test="ElementCount &lt; 1001">ElementCount elemanın değeri en fazla 1000 olabilir..</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>     

<sch:rule abstract="true" id="ElementListCountCheck">
    <sch:assert test="count(ElementList/*) = ElementCount ">ElementList elemanı içersinde bulunan eleman sayısı ElementCount elemanı değerine eşit olmalıdır.</sch:assert>
</sch:rule>...
```

Main Validation XML (execute rules with context)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sch:schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" 
            xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" 
            xmlns:sh="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader" 
            xmlns:ef="http://www.efatura.gov.tr/envelope-namespace">

    <sch:include href="UBL-TR_Codelist.xml#codes"/>
    <sch:include href="UBL-TR_Common_Schematron.xml#abstracts"/>    

    <sch:ns prefix="sh" uri="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader" />
    <sch:ns prefix="ef" uri="http://www.efatura.gov.tr/package-namespace" />
    <sch:ns prefix="inv" uri="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" />
    <sch:ns prefix="apr" uri="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:ApplicationResponse-2" />
    <sch:ns prefix="cac" uri="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" />
    <sch:ns prefix="cbc" uri="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" />
    <sch:ns prefix="ext" uri="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" />
    <sch:ns prefix="ds" uri="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" />
    <sch:ns prefix="xades" uri="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" />   
    <sch:ns prefix="hr" uri="http://www.hr-xml.org/3" />
    <sch:ns prefix="oa" uri="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" />

    <let name="envelopeType" value="/sh:StandardBusinessDocument/sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader/sh:DocumentIdentification/sh:Type"/>
    <let name="senderId" value="/sh:StandardBusinessDocument/sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader/sh:Sender/sh:ContactInformation[sh:ContactTypeIdentifier = 'VKN_TCKN']/sh:Contact"/>
    <let name="senderAlias" value="/sh:StandardBusinessDocument/sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader/sh:Sender/sh:Identifier"/>
    <let name="receiverId" value="/sh:StandardBusinessDocument/sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader/sh:Receiver/sh:ContactInformation[sh:ContactTypeIdentifier = 'VKN_TCKN']/sh:Contact"/>
    <let name="receiverAlias" value="/sh:StandardBusinessDocument/sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader/sh:Receiver/sh:Identifier"/>
    <let name="responseCode" value="//apr:ApplicationResponse/cac:DocumentResponse/cac:Response/cbc:ResponseCode" />

    <!-- StandardBusinessDocument -->
    <sch:pattern id="document">
        <sch:rule context="sh:StandardBusinessDocument">
            <sch:extends rule="DocumentCheck"/>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>

    <!-- StandardBusinessDocumentHeader -->
    <sch:pattern id="header">
        <sch:rule context="sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader">
            <sch:extends rule="HeaderCheck"/>
        </sch:rule>

        <sch:rule context="sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader/sh:Sender/sh:Identifier">
            <sch:extends rule="EmptyCheck"/>
        </sch:rule>

        <sch:rule context="sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader/sh:Receiver/sh:Identifier">
            <sch:extends rule="EmptyCheck"/>
        </sch:rule>

        <sch:rule context="sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader/sh:Sender">
            <sch:extends rule="ContactInformationCheck"/>
        </sch:rule>

        <sch:rule context="sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader/sh:Receiver">
            <sch:extends rule="ContactInformationCheck"/>
        </sch:rule>

        <sch:rule context="sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader/sh:Sender/sh:ContactInformation">
            <sch:extends rule="ContactCheck"/>
        </sch:rule>
...
```

Code List XML

```
    <sch:schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" 
            xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">

    <sch:pattern name="CodeList" id="codes">
        <sch:let name="ProfileIDType"   value="',TICARIFATURA,TEMELFATURA,'"/>
        <sch:let name="InvoiceTypeCodeList" value="',SATIS,IADE,'"/>
        <sch:let name="EnvelopeType"    value="',SENDERENVELOPE,POSTBOXENVELOPE,SYSTEMENVELOPE,USERENVELOPE,'"/> 
        <sch:let name="ElementType" value="',INVOICE,APPLICATIONRESPONSE,PROCESSUSERACCOUNT,CANCELUSERACCOUNT,'"/>
        <sch:let name="TaxType" value="',0003,0015,0061,0071,0073,0074,0075,0076,0077,1047,1048,4080,4081,9015,9021,9077,8001,8002,8003,8004,8005,8006,8007,8008,'"/>
        <sch:let name="PartyIdentificationIDType" value="',TCKN,VKN,HIZMETNO,MUSTERINO,TESISATNO,TELEFONNO,DISTRIBUTORNO,TICARETSICILNO,TAPDKNO,BAYINO,ABONENO,SAYACNO,'"/>
        <sch:let name="ResponseCodeType" value="',KABUL,RED,IADE,S_APR,'"/>
        <sch:let name="ContactTypeIdentifierType" value="',UNVAN,VKN_TCKN,'"/>
        <sch:let name="CurrencyCodeList" value="',AED,AFN,ALL,AMD,ANG,AOA,ARS,AUD,AWG,AZM,BAM,BBD,BDT,BGN,BHD,BIF,BMD,BND,BOB,BRL,BSD,BTN,BWP,BYR,BZD,CAD,CDF,CHF,CLP,CNY,COP,CRC,CUP,CVE,CYP,CZK,DJF,DKK,DOP,DZD,EEK,EGP,ERN,ETB,EUR,FJD,FKP,GBP,GEL,GHC,GIP,GMD,GNF,GTQ,GYD,HKD,HNL,HRK,HTG,HUF,IDR,ILS,INR,IQD,IRR,ISK,JMD,JOD,JPY,KES,KGS,KHR,KMF,KPW,KRW,KWD,KYD,KZT,LAK,LBP,LKR,LRD,LSL,LTL,LVL,LYD,MAD,MDL,MGF,MKD,MMK,MNT,MOP,MRO,MTL,MUR,MVR,MWK,MXN,MYR,MZM,NAD,NGN,NIO,NOK,NPR,NZD,OMR,PAB,PEN,PGK,PHP,PKR,PLN,PYG,QAR,ROL,RUB,RWF,SAR,SBD,SCR,SDD,SEK,SGD,SHP,SIT,SKK,SLL,SOS,SRG,STD,SVC,SYP,SZL,THB,TJS,TMM,TND,TOP,TRL,TTD,TWD,TZS,UAH,UGX,USD,UYU,UZS,VEB,VND,VUV,WST,XAF,XAG,XAU,XCD,XDR,XOF,XPD,XPF,XPT,YER,YUM,ZAR,ZMK,ZWD,'"/>
        <sch:let name="CountryCodeList" value="',AF,AX,AL,DZ,AS,AD,AO,AI,AQ,AG,AR,AM,AW,AU,AT,AZ,BS,BH,BD,BB,BY,BE,BZ,BJ,BM,BT,BO,BA,BW,BV,BR,IO,BN,BG,BF,BI,KH,CM,CA,CV,KY,CF,TD,CL,CN,CX,CC,CO,KM,CG,CD,CK,CR,CI,HR,CU,CY,CZ,DK,DJ,DM,DO,EC,EG,SV,GQ,ER,EE,ET,FK,FO,FJ,FI,FR,GF,PF,TF,GA,GM,GE,DE,GH,GI,GR,GL,GD,GP,GU,GT,GG,GN,GW,GY,HT,HM,VA,HN,HK,HU,IS,IN,ID,IR,IQ,IE,IM,IL,IT,JM,JP,JE,JO,KZ,KE,KI,KP,KR,KW,KG,LA,LV,LB,LS,LR,LY,LI,LT,LU,MO,MK,MG,MW,MY,MV,ML,MT,MH,MQ,MR,MU,YT,MX,FM,MD,MC,MN,ME,MS,MA,MZ,MM,NA,NR,NP,NL,AN,NC,NZ,NI,NE,NG,NU,NF,MP,NO,OM,PK,PW,PS,PA,PG,PY,PE,PH,PN,PL,PT,PR,QA,RE,RO,RU,RW,BL,SH,KN,LC,MF,PM,VC,WS,SM,ST,SA,SN,RS,SC,SL,SG,SK,SI,SB,SO,ZA,GS,ES,LK,SD,SR,SJ,SZ,SE,CH,SY,TW,TJ,TZ,TH,TL,TG,TK,TO,TT,TN,TR,TM,TC,TV,UG,UA,AE,GB,US,UM,UY,UZ,VU,VE,VN,VG,VI,WF,EH,YE,ZM,ZW,'"/>
        <sch:let name="UserType" value="',1,2,11,12,'"/>
        <sch:let name="ReservedAliases" value="',usergb,GIB,'"/>
    </sch:pattern>  

</sch:schema>
```

I could not share all files completely, exceeded body max character...

For xsl file i combined these 3 XML files and give this combined xml to Oxygen XML Editor and i used XSL file that Oxygen Editor's output for my combined xml. (Oxygen Editor ignored include statements at second XML, so i combined all XML files as one XML file manually).

Small Part Of Xsl;

```
      <axsl:choose>
         <axsl:when test="ef:Package"/>
         <axsl:otherwise>
            <axsl:message>ef:Package zorunlu bir elemandır.<axsl:text> (</axsl:text>ef:Package<axsl:text>)</axsl:text>
               <axsl:text> [</axsl:text>assert<axsl:text>]</axsl:text>
            </axsl:message>
         </axsl:otherwise>
      </axsl:choose>
      <axsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()" mode="M19"/>
   </axsl:template>
   <axsl:template match="text()" priority="-1" mode="M19"/>
   <axsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="-2" mode="M19">
      <axsl:choose><!--Housekeeping: SAXON warns if attempting to find the attribute
                           of an attribute-->
         <axsl:when test="not(@*)">
            <axsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="M19"/>
         </axsl:when>
         <axsl:otherwise>
            <axsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="M19"/>
         </axsl:otherwise>
      </axsl:choose>
   </axsl:template>

<!--PATTERN header-->


    <!--RULE -->

   <axsl:template match="sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader" priority="109" mode="M20">

        <!--ASSERT -->

      <axsl:choose>
         <axsl:when test="sh:HeaderVersion = '1.0'"/>
         <axsl:otherwise>
            <axsl:message>Geçersiz sh:HeaderVersion elemanı değeri. sh:HeaderVersion elemanı '1.0' değerine eşit olmalıdır.<axsl:text> (</axsl:text>sh:HeaderVersion = '1.0'<axsl:text>)</axsl:text>
               <axsl:text> [</axsl:text>assert<axsl:text>]</axsl:text>
            </axsl:message>
         </axsl:otherwise>
      </axsl:choose>

        <!--ASSERT -->

      <axsl:choose>
         <axsl:when test="count(sh:Sender) = 1"/>
         <axsl:otherwise>
            <axsl:message>sh:Sender zorunlu bir elemandır.<axsl:text> (</axsl:text>count(sh:Sender) = 1<axsl:text>)</axsl:text>
               <axsl:text> [</axsl:text>assert<axsl:text>]</axsl:text>
            </axsl:message>
         </axsl:otherwise>
      </axsl:choose>

        <!--ASSERT -->

      <axsl:choose>
         <axsl:when test="count(sh:Receiver) = 1"/>
         <axsl:otherwise>
            <axsl:message>sh:Receiver zorunlu bir elemandır.<axsl:text> (</axsl:text>count(sh:Receiver) = 1<axsl:text>)</axsl:text>
               <axsl:text> [</axsl:text>assert<axsl:text>]</axsl:text>
            </axsl:message>
         </axsl:otherwise>
      </axsl:choose>
      <axsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()" mode="M20"/>
   </axsl:template>

    <!--RULE -->

   <axsl:template match="sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader/sh:Sender/sh:Identifier" priority="108" mode="M20">

        <!--ASSERT -->

      <axsl:choose>
         <axsl:when test="string-length(normalize-space(string(.))) != 0"/>
         <axsl:otherwise>
            <axsl:message>Geçersiz <axsl:text/>
               <axsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
               <axsl:text/> elemanı değeri. Boş olmayan bir değer içermelidir.<axsl:text> (</axsl:text>string-length(normalize-space(string(.))) != 0<axsl:text>)</axsl:text>
               <axsl:text> [</axsl:text>assert<axsl:text>]</axsl:text>
            </axsl:message>
         </axsl:otherwise>
      </axsl:choose>
      <axsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()" mode="M20"/>
   </axsl:template>
```

**SOLVED WITH *Michael Kay*'s Answer**

Wrote simply this class:

```
public void Message(XdmNode content, bool terminate, IXmlLocation location) {
    //System.Console.WriteLine("content: " + content.BaseUri);
    System.Console.WriteLine("content: " + content.Count);
    System.Console.WriteLine("content: " + content.NodeKind.ToString());
    System.Console.WriteLine("content: " + content.StringValue);
    System.Console.WriteLine("content: " + content.OuterXml);

    System.Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

    System.Console.WriteLine("terminate: " + terminate);

    System.Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

    System.Console.WriteLine("terminate: " + location.BaseUri);
    System.Console.WriteLine("terminate: " + location.LineNumber);


    System.Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
    System.Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
    System.Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
    System.Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
    System.Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

}
```

And try;

```
MyMessageListener myMessageListener = new MyMessageListener();
transformer.MessageListener = myMessageListener;
```

And MessageListener class can handle the validation error messages.

Comment: Also note the URIs only use forwards slashes so it should be `new Uri(@"file:///C:/path/to/my.xml");` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The output of xsl:message can be redirected by setting the MessageListener property on the XsltTransformer object. You need to implement the IMessageListener interface, which has one method Message(). The content of the message is supplied as an XdmNode; if your message is a simple string (rather than structured XML) then you can simply use the StringValue property of this node to get the message content.

I suspect that the reason the principal result tree is empty is that you are not writing anything to it; that is, your only output is xsl:message output. I can't confirm this without seeing your full stylesheet.

Comment: as i said, my main purpose, validate values for an XML with schematron. For this i have 3 xml files that contains validation rules for XML values. I did not know what should i. And I create an xsl file from these 3 xml (via Oxygen XML Editor). With this XSL file i can validate XML in Java (you can see example code in first post), but .NET gives errors. Full scenario is this; do schematron validation for XML file with given 3 xml files. I will update first post to show xml files contents (schamtron validation xml files) and xsl file created by Oxygen XML Editor with these xml files.

Comment: **(validation rule functions contains XSLT 2.0, that is why i am trying this operation with Saxon API).**

Comment: thanks, MessageListener is what i want, and i updated my first post for answer. One question more; is there easy way to do schematron validation to an XML file according to given other 3 XML files. Is this right way; 1- Create an XSL file from validation XML files; use a 3. party app like Oxygen XML editor etc. for this 2-) Use 3. party api like saxon. Is there any native way in .NET for this. Every step require (manually) intervention. For step 1; combine 3 files to one XML file (input) and fix faulty expression for Oxygen output. step 2; write MessageListener vs...

Comment: That seems a completely unrelated question. Start with a clean slate.

Comment: @sem have you found an easy way to validate xml files ? and also work on net core ? :)